# How to trim a recorded video from the camera in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video-capture

I am developing an iOS application which is used to upload videos to the server, my problem is that after recording an unlimited video from the camera , the user is allowed to select  a maximum 3 min length video from the full length video. But in case of selecting the video from the photo library it is working only by setting the `VideoRecordMaxDuration` to 180 sec. How do I solve this ?